# htaccess Перенаправление запросов в суб-директорию

Tags: .htaccess, php

Есть корень сайта www, в котором лежит .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Данный код выполняет перенаправление запросов в директорию www/public, где, в свою очередь, лежит .htaccess, в котором:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

все перенаправляется на index.php

И, как бы, все работает нормально, пока не вводим в адресной строке

> www.[name].com/public

Происходит прямое обращение на index.php и public уже воспринимается не как запрос, а как переход в директорию. Помогите решить данную проблему. Если что не понятно описал, - говорите, попробую уточнить.

Comment: А почему бы не сделать через переадресацию в папку public?

Answer (score 1):

можно добавить в первый файл перед первым правилом

```
RewriteRule ^public$ public/index.php [L]
```

Comment: не сработало :((